# Tailwind styles in global.css base are not been applied

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have some styling in my global.css file

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
    .body {
        @apply bg-[#141414] text-white; // This is supposed to change the color of the entire body but it is not working
    }
}

@layer components {
    
  .headerLink {
    @apply cursor-pointer text-sm font-light text-[#e5e5e5] transition duration-[.4s] hover:text-[#b3b3b3];
  }
}
```

the .headerLink in the components works but the base does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so it was a typo. It was supposed to be `body {}`
but I made it `.body {}`